# What is the equivalent of wget in javascript to download a file from a given url?

Tags: javascript, download, wget

"wget http://www.example.com/file.doc" downloads that file to the local disk.

What is the equivalent of the above in javascript? for example, consider the following html snippet.

```
<html>
<head>
   <script language="JavaScript">
      function download_file() {
         var url = "http://www.example.com/file.doc"
         //
         // Question: 
         //
         // what should be done here to download 
         // the file in the url?
         //
      }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <input type="button" value="Download" onclick="download_file()">
</body>
</html>
```

Please suggest a solution that is compliant with all the browsers.

Sangeeth.

Comment: This is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349067/download-a-file-using-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a exploring more than a month, with a help of my friend, we were able to find out the following.

The website where the file is hosted is not allowing us to download the file using `window.location = url;` or `window.open(url);`

Finally we had to use the `data-downloadurl` support from `HTML5` as follows

```
<a href="<url-goes-here>" data-downloadurl="audio/mpeg:<filename-goes-here>:<url-goes-here>" download="<filename-goes-here>">Click here to download the file</a>
```

We embed this html into the host html and when clicked on the link, it triggers the download.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use:

```
 function download_file() {
   var url = "http://www.example.com/file.doc"
   window.location = url;
 }
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

If you need to open this in a new window/tab first then use:

```
 function download_file() {
   var url = "http://www.example.com/file.doc"
   window.open(url);
 }
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open

Comment: window.location is something I learnt today. Thanks! But this is not helping me in downloading the file from the URL to my hdd. This just opens the file in the browser. What I'm looking for is something similar to right-click & "Save Link As.." option. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well it seems that this is going to be something quite dependent on your setup. Most webservers send *.doc files as attachments by setting the http response header [`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.doc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields). It's up to the browser to display the dialog box or not using this as a hint. Maybe you have a MS office plugin enabled that you just need to disable.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that always comes in mind of every answerer to this question is executing wget shell command from java script.I'm almost certain that that's not possible because of
major security risk.

You pretty much need to have ajax which sends command to command line
either through php, or another scripting language via ajax...

You could probably make that happen with something like http://www.phantomjs.org/
I am saying probably because I read it from somewhere.

Comment: Executing `wget` from my browser... never even entered my mind as a possibility. Just set it as a link, or the document's href, and it'll prompt you to download it.

Comment: I didnt said Executing `wget` from my browser

Comment: Even though the OP clearly wants to download it from a web page? Interesting approach, then, not using a browser.

Comment: Looking at http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart, downloading a file from the given URL seems possible.. But I'm looking for a JavaScript equivalent of that!

Comment: I've tried various mime types f.e. "data:text/attachment", "Content-disposition:attachment", "application/octet-stream", etc with window.open(), window.location.href, etc but no luck. I've searched stackoverflow and found that many people had come across the similar situation and no one have a convincing answer! .. I'm going to continue looking for a solution.