# javascript how to download on clicking link using adobe

Tags: c#, javascript, file, pdf, download

I need to download when the link is clicked and a PDF document whose path i provide needs to be downloaded...what i use is the following:

```
<a href="file://serveraddress/coverage.pdf"  download> click</a>
```

also tried

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.execCommand("SaveAs",true,"file://server/coverage.pdf");" >31 MB</a>;
```

but it doesnt work.

its not redirecting or downloading or anything!

i tried the above in chrome and firefox , but it doesnt work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download a file using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349067/download-a-file-using-javascript/).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<a href="//serveraddress/coverage.pdf" target="_blank">Click to download</a>
```

Comment: this works for local , but considering that its on another server it says Failed no file...meaning its trying to load but its unable to do so i guess. not sure why , because if i put the path directly in a browser it gets the file

Comment: @user3218288 This should work in both the cases as we are opening the file to be downloaded in a new tab using `target="_blank"`.

Comment: Also the above downloads(considering local rendition) a html page not PDF

Comment: @user3218288 Then you can use some php/asp/jsp script for this something like `<a href="download.php?url=//serverAddress/coverage.pdf">Download</a>` which will fetch the file and throw on user's browser.