# How do you automatically download a file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, image, download, href

So, I've been looking and trying to find a way to download a file automatically right when somebody goes onto my site. I've tried using an a tag to download, and it works, you just have to click to download it. Like so...

```html
<a href="pic.jpg" download>Download</a>
```

But I don't want that. I want it to automatically download with no click. I need some help please!

Comment: So you mean there would not be anything else on your website and just when user clicks the url of your website, the file should get downloaded?

Comment: Sorry - Answered but didn't realise you already tried the download attribute. Still, this is best done server side, using a 'Content-disposition: attachment' header when serving the file

Comment: You can bind a function on html <a href="pic.jpg" onclick="download('pic.jpg')">Download</a> and download function open a window with file url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download a file using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349067/download-a-file-using-javascript)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it's an actual file (something that won't simply display in your browser like a JPG file) then you could use a javascript or meta redirect.

`<script> document.location.href = 'yourfile.exe'; </script>`

or

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=yourfile.exe">`

But I am wondering if you might be talking about the user being asked if they want to open or save a file (whether it's a JPG or whatever?)

Answer (score 9):

Another way to do it :

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute('href', dataUri);
a.setAttribute('download', filename);

var aj = $(a);
aj.appendTo('body');
aj[0].click();
aj.remove();
```

Comment: Wonderful to see both methods. The above method won't open a .jpg or a .pdf in the browser ! Woenderful

Answer (score 4):

Another option which is pure javascript is:

```
const downloadFile = (file) => {
  const element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'Download Btn');
  element.setAttribute('download', file);

  element.style.display = 'none';

  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();
  document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

And then you can call the function on load:

```
downloadFile(/*pass your file here*/);
```

Comment: what is the type of file? I tried typing it as "File" but got an error